# Grouped by on a binned column not working correct

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am using pandas cut to calculate a new bins column, as below:

```
bins = [1, 10, 20, 34, np.Inf]
labels = ['1-10', '11-20', '21-34', '35 -Inf']
df['binned'] = pd.cut(df['Number of Locations'], bins=bins, labels=labels, include_lowest=True)
```

This gives me new column for binned values,

Then I try below code:

```
df.groupby(['binned', 'Parent_Account'])['has_desired_product'].apply(sum).reset_index()
```

this is suposed to give me grouped by the new binned column but it gives me incorrect output -there is actually only one Parent_Account for '35-inf' bin but it shows more than that, do I have error in my code somewhere?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No sample data provided.  Testing edge cases all seems fine. I'm using pandas 1.1

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Number of Locations":[32,33,34,35,36,np.inf,np.nan,34.0001]})
bins = [1, 10, 20, 34, np.Inf]
labels = ['1-10', '11-20', '21-34', '35 -Inf']
df['binned'] = pd.cut(df['Number of Locations'], bins=bins, labels=labels, include_lowest=True)
print(df.to_string())
```

**output**

```
   Number of Locations   binned
0              32.0000    21-34
1              33.0000    21-34
2              34.0000    21-34
3              35.0000  35 -Inf
4              36.0000  35 -Inf
5                  inf  35 -Inf
6                  NaN      NaN
7              34.0001  35 -Inf
```